# How to set up functional private network bridge on qemu/kvm?

Tags: kvm, qemu, dhcp, bridge

**System**

My host is running Fedora 29, and my internet connection is wifi. Note that I am using X.org, not wayland; the SDL option in qemu doesn't work on wayland, and the curses option has trouble booting up.

**Problem**

I need to set up a lot of different VMs that can talk to each other on this host, for the purpose of an academic experiment.

**My attempt**

I followed this guide: https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking. Based on what it said, it seems I need a private virtual bridge between all my guests so that they can communicate. I executed `sudo nano /etc/qemu-ifup` and copied the following from the guide:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x

switch=br0

if [ -n "$1" ];then
        # tunctl -u `whoami` -t $1 (use ip tuntap instead!)
        ip tuntap add $1 mode tap user `whoami`
        ip link set $1 up
        sleep 0.5s
        # brctl addif $switch $1 (use ip link instead!)
        ip link set $1 master $switch
        exit 0
else
        echo "Error: no interface specified"
        exit 1
fi
```

I then created the directory `~/VMs` and executed `nano ~/VMs/randmac` and copied in

```
#!/bin/bash
# generate a random mac address for the qemu nic
printf 'DE:AD:BE:EF:%02X:%02X\n' $((RANDOM%256)) $((RANDOM%256))
```

I downloaded a minimal Ubuntu iso from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso, and used the following commands:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/qemu-ifup
cd ~/VMs
cp ~/Downloads/mini.iso .
chmod 755 ./randmac
sudo ip link add br0 type bridge
sudo ifconfig br0 up
qemu-img create -f qcow2 ubuntu-server-0.img 2G
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -hda ubuntu-server-0.img \
-sdl -cdrom mini.iso -machine type=q35,accel=kvm \
-cpu host -smp 2 -m 512 \
-device e1000,netdev=net0,mac=`./randmac` -netdev tap,id=net0
```

The Live CD successfully booted, but the installer fails to connect to the network: it produces this error:

[image]

It then asks me to provide an IP, which, as far as I know, is not something I have. During the execution of the qemu command, the terminal output is:

```
+ switch=br0
+ '[' -n tap0 ']'
++ whoami
+ ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap user root
ioctl(TUNSETIFF): Device or resource busy
+ ip link set tap0 up
+ sleep 0.5s
+ ip link set tap0 master br0
+ exit 0
```

**Question**

Does anyone know what I did wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: It really appears that you've successfully connected your guests to an isolated private network. It's your own private network, so unless you want to run a DHCP server... just make up some IPs. Ideally from one of the RFC1918 private network ranges, but really you can use any IPs you want. It's not connected to the Internet. BTW: if you use libvirt and virt-manager, it can handle a lot of this stuff for you...

Comment: Ah, I see that my problem is one of reading comprehension. Someday, I should really learn how networks work... Unfortunately, it seems like my wireless drivers will not allow me to connect them to a bridge: `sudo ip link set wlp2s0 master br0` resulted in `Error: Device does not allow enslaving to a bridge.`

Comment: New question 1: How would I use libvirt to let my VMs communicate with each other and with the internet?

New question 2: I don't actually need the internet on these VMs, except in that I do need to install some packages on the original VM to get them set up, and internet access makes that easier. Would it cause problems if I installed a VM with the standard networking settings, and then ran it with the private bridge?

Comment: In virt-manager, you go to properties on the local QEMU/KVM, then virtual networks. You can add/edit them there. If you just want outgoing connections for package downloads, set up one that forwards to a physical network via NAT. (Probably the default). You can set up a second isolated virtual network. It'll even set up DHCP for you, so you don't have to manually assign IPs. You can add two interfaces to your VMs if you want them on both networks.

Comment: @Zorgoth about the wireless limitation, it's not really a driver limitation, it's related to how wifi is working which can't be mapped as is to ethernet for the case of a STA (client) rather than AP case. Look at this: [Four layer-2 addresses in 802.11 frame header](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25100/four-layer-2-addresses-in-802-11-frame-header). [4addr mode](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw#using_4-address_for_ap_and_client_mode) is supported by a few drivers, but must *also* be configured on the AP, and will prevent other STA to connect.